# Datatype for storing barcodes in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, types, barcode

Hai guys,

- What datatype you would suggest for storing barcode values in sql server 2005?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A barcode typically simply is a graphical representation of some string value, e.g. letter and numbers - so I'd just store that string (usually a product code or something like that) in a VARCHAR(x) field and not bother storing the actual graphical barcode at all.

If you must store the graphical representation of the barcode for whatever reason, use a VARBINARY(MAX) field - gives you up to 2 GB of binary storage.

Comment: VARCHAR(50) beacsue varbinary nnot store 8722700040620